# How to read from service bus topic deadletter queue c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

below code works fine to read service bus queue deadletter but for topic even after changing path it it throwing exception path is not correct.

```
string path= "QueueName";

MessagingFactory messageFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("ConnecitonString");

MessageReceiver deadletterReceiver = await         messageFactory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync(QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(path), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

MessageSender sender = await messageFactory.CreateMessageSenderAsync(path);

BrokeredMessage deadLetter = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
if (deadLetter != null)
{
```

Now I want to do the same for Service Bus Topic DeadLetter 
So path should be - `topicName/subscriptionName`

```
 string path= "TopicName/SubscriptionName";

    MessagingFactory messageFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("ConnecitonString");

    MessageReceiver deadletterReceiver = await messageFactory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync(TopicClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(path), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

    MessageSender sender = await messageFactory.CreateMessageSenderAsync(path);

    BrokeredMessage deadLetter = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.Zero);
    if (deadLetter != null)
    {
```

Getting exception path is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topics don't have dead-lettered queues, subscriptions do. What you need to use it [SubscriptionClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.formatdeadletterpath?view=azure-dotnet) method, passing topic and subscription names.